# Hystrix default timeout not work

Tags: timeout, hystrix, netflix-ribbon, feign

set default timeout like this

```
hystrix:
  threadpool:
    default:
      coreSize: 500
      maxQueueSize: 1000
      queueSizeRejectionThreshold: 800
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
```

Ribbon:

```
ribbon:
  eager-load:
    enabled: true
    clients: dcit-auth,dcit-service-upms,dcmd-service-demand
  Httpclient:
    enabled: false
  OkHttp:
    enabled: true
  ReadTimeout: 30000
  ConnectTimeout: 30000
```

feign:

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true
  okhttp:
    enabled: true
  httpclient:
    enabled: false
  client:
    config:
      feignName:
        connectTimeout: 30000
        readTimeout: 30000
  compression:
    request:
      enabled: true
    response:
      enabled: true
```

hystrix metics for my service:

"gauge.servo.hystrix.hystrixcommand.ribboncommand.myservice.propertyvalue_executiontimeoutinmilliseconds": 2000,

Each time myservice response over 2s will return 500 timeout error.

Why dose the timeout setting not work?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution?

Comment: @KadzhaevMarat No, give up and I just update to Spring Boot 2.0 to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are hitting the Feign timeout.
Use feign.client.config.**default** instead feign.client.config.**feignName** to define that to all Feign Clients in your application.